# Retrieve Facebook Profile Posts (Status) on Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Android and Java Development and I am trying to figure out a way to retrieve the current users Profile posts and save it in a Text File on my smart phone for further processes.

I am able to retrieve User Name, Email, Gender, Age Range and Birthday. so far everything works fine and the text file is being written when Facebook is connected with my Application.

Below class is how its coded in order to retrieve the mentioned Data, If anyone does know of how to retrieve posts as well via this method, please suggest?

Thanks!

```
package com.example.daunte_pc.anique;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class SocialActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private static final String TAG = "SocialActivity";
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    URL profile_pic;
    String id;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_status","user_posts"));


        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SocialActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait! Anique_Profile's being processed!");
                progressDialog.show();
                String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                Log.i("accessToken",accessToken);



                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.i("Test",response.toString());

                        Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);
                        String name = bFacebookData.getString( "name");
                        String email = bFacebookData.getString( "email");
                        String gender = bFacebookData.getString( "gender");
                        String profilepic = bFacebookData.getString( "profile_pic");
                        String age_range = bFacebookData.getString( "age_range");
                        String birthday = bFacebookData.getString( "birthday");
                        String posts = bFacebookData.getString( "posts{message}");



                        Intent in = new Intent(SocialActivity.this, Facebook_Profile.class);
                        in.putExtra("name", name);
                        in.putExtra("email", email);
                        in.putExtra("gender", gender);
                        in.putExtra("Image", profilepic);
                        in.putExtra("posts", posts);

                        startActivity(in);

                        try{
                            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Anique Text Files");
                            if (! root.exists()){
                                root.mkdir();
                            }

                            File filePath = new File(root, "myFile.txt");
                            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
                            writer.append("Name : "+ name+"\n");
                            writer.append("\n");
                            writer.append("Email : "+ email+"\n");
                            writer.append("\n");
                            writer.append("Gender : "+ gender+"\n");
                            writer.append("\n");
                            writer.append("Age : "+ age_range+"\n");
                            writer.append("\n");
                            writer.append("Birthday : "+ birthday+"\n");
                            writer.append("\n");
                            writer.append("Posts : "+ posts+"\n");
                            writer.append("\n");
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();
                            Toast.makeText(SocialActivity.this,"Success!! Logged into Anique_Profile as per given user information. ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(SocialActivity.this, "Data is Written!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }catch (Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        progressDialog.hide();
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, age_range, birthday, posts, feed");
                request.setParameters(params);
                request.executeAsync();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            }
        });
    }

    private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        try{
            id = object.getString("id");
            profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=200&height=200");
            Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic +"");
            bundle.putString("profile_pic",profile_pic.toString());
        }catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bundle.putString("idFacebook",id);

        if(object.has("name")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("name", object.getString("name"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("email")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("gender")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("age_range")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("age_range", object.getString("age_range"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("birthday")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("birthday", object.getString("birthday"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(object.has("posts")){
            try{
                bundle.putString("posts", object.getString("posts"));
            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return bundle;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: _“to retrieve the current users Profile posts and save it in a Text File on my smart phone for further processes”_ - you need to do something with the data that more or less directly benefits the user’s “in-app experience” to begin with ... Facebook will not approve this in review, if the sole purpose is background analysis of the data that has no direct connection to the user experience.

Comment: I understood. I want to get current users profile statuses for catching particular key words to predict something. There is no objection in showing the posts to user on my App. But that doesn't seem inappropriate since prediction is involved here. To be clear, still the user has nothing to do with his posts directly. Your suggestion? is it yet okay? @CBroe

Comment: Unless you are making that “prediction” for the benefit of the user - no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get current users profile statuses for catching particular key words to predict something. There is no objection in showing the posts to user on my App. But that doesn't seem inappropriate since prediction is involved here.

You need to do something with the data that more or less directly benefits the user’s “in-app experience” to begin with ... Facebook will not approve this in review, if the sole purpose is background analysis of the data that has no direct connection to the user experience.

The permission necessary to read a user’s posts would be `user_posts`, but documentation lists this as one of the non-applicable use cases:

> Non-visible use of this data such as sentiment analysis or guarding against spam bots.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-user_posts

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, i figured out a way.